# How are Lambda Expressions Translated Into Java Byte Code

Tags: java, lambda, jvm, java-8, compiler-theory

I am trying to create an example using lambda expression in java and i am using offical JDK8. My example was run successfully. But when i trying to check how the compiler translate lambda expression into byte code, this makes me some confusion.Following is the code of my example:-

```
public class LambdaTest {
    public Integer lambdaBinaryOpertor(BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator) {
        return binaryOperator.apply(60, 72);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LambdaTest test = new LambdaTest();
        BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator = (a, b) -> a*b;
        System.out.println("Additon using Lambda BinaryOperator: "+test.lambdaBinaryOpertor(binaryOperator));
    }
}
```

In this [Article](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html), they discuss about how compiler translate the lambda expressions into byte code. According to this document the lambda expression convert into `static` method and the location where lambda expression declare, have reference of lambda `static` method. The following example is in the article :

```
//Source code
class A {
    public void foo() {
        List<String> list = ...
        list.forEach( s -> { System.out.println(s); } );
    }
} 

//After compile above code "translate code " 
class A {
    public void foo() {
        List<String> list = ...
        list.forEach( [lambda for lambda$1 as Block] );
    }

    static void lambda$1(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

My example run fine and give us the appropriate result. But when i trying to run the `javap` command for check the byte code of class, there is no static method for lambdas in byte code.

```
c:\>javap LambdaTest
Compiled from "LambdaTest.java"
public class LambdaTest {
public LambdaTest();
public java.lang.Integer lambdaBinaryOpertor(java.util.function.BinaryOperator <java.lang.Integer>);
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

In the case of generics, bridge method is created by compiler and we will also check this method using `javap` command, but in the case of lambdas there is no `static` method. The article was published at 2012 and java 8 was launch at march 2014. So i have some queries regarding transnational of lambda:

1. Is there any new implementation used for lambda in JDK 8 after this article release or i will do something wrong to check the lambda method ?
2. How really the compiler deal with lambda expression?
3. How the JVM invoke the lambda exression ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use **javap** additional arguments to print full information about class: **javap -v -p -s -c**

For your example, source code of lambda will be:

```
private static java.lang.Integer lambda$main$0(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokevirtual #17                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
         4: aload_1       
         5: invokevirtual #17                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
         8: imul          
         9: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        12: areturn       
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      13     0     a   Ljava/lang/Integer;
            0      13     1     b   Ljava/lang/Integer;
}
```