# Remote execution client possible with ASM?

Tags: java, lambda, java-bytecode-asm

I wish to create a custom remote execution client for my app. The client may look something like this:

```
interface Client {

    <T> T computeRemotely(Function<List<MyBigObject>, T> consumer)
}
```

and might be used like this:

```
Client client = new Client();
Integer remoteResult = client.computeRemotely(list -> {
    Integer result = -1;

    // do some computational work here.

    return result;
});
```

This means I somehow need to take lambda from the client, send it to the server, run the function (passing in a real `List<MyBigObject>`) and send the result back.

It's worth noting that a restriction on using my client library is that you cannot use anything outside the JDK in that lambda and expect it to work (as the classes may not be on the classpath on the server)...but I would like them to be able to use any of the JDK classes to bring in their own data to the calculation.

Now I can't just  serialize the `Function<MyBigObject, T>` lambda because it serializes like an inner client of whatever class the lambda exists in which will NOT be on the classpath on the server.

So I have been looking at ASM to see whether that could work. Given that I have never done byte code manipulation before, I just wanted to check that what I am saying sounds right:

- I can use ASM to convert to read the class that the lambda sits in.
- Using a Method Visitor, get the method bytes, send them to the server
- Use ASM to create an instance from the bytes and execute it.

Given that the lambda is like an anonymous inner class, I am guessing I will have to do some sort of method renaming in there too..

Is this roughly correct or have I got completely the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: I am not familiar with lambda implementation, so not sure if any renaming is needed. But if it is, you need to rename everywhere - in particular in bytecode of methods - any access to fields and methods of renamed class.  Not that difficult perhaps, but good to keep in mind. There are Remapper and org.objectweb.asm.commons.RemappingClassAdapter classes, which seem able to handle the renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Note that lambdas can access all immutable values from their context. Thus, you'd need to either forbid accessing external values (which would severely limit the usefulness of your solution) or identify them and send representations of those values (which runs into the problem you mentioned; their implementation may be outside the server classpath).

So even if you send the method representation (for which you would not even need ASM; you could get the Resource directly from the classloader), it won't work for the general case.

Edit: Given your comment, it could work. You'd need to synthesize a class with

- The context attributes as final fields
- A constructor with arguments for all the fields (you will passed the deserialized values there on construction)
- The lambda method — see [this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133243/how-lambda-expressions-are-translate-in-java-byte-code)

Comment: What I was planning on doing is allowing access to any immutable values that were part of the JDK (ie Lists, Collections etc...) but no custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in analyzing the runtime generated classes of lambda expressions. They have a very simple structure which they reveal when being serialized. During Serialization they will get replaced by a [`SerializedLambda`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html) instance which contains all information you could ever gather, most notably:

- [The implemented `interface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html#getFunctionalInterfaceClass--)
- [The](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html#getImplClass--) [target](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html#getImplMethodName--) [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html#getImplMethodSignature--) that will be invoked
- [The captured values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html#getCapturedArg-int-)

The crucial point is the target method. For lambda expressions (unlike method references) the target method is a synthetic method that resides within the class which contains the lambda expression. That method is `private`, by the way, that’s why an attempt to replicate the class invoking that method is doomed to fail, special JVM interaction is required to make it possible to create such a class. But the important point is that you need the *target method* on the remote side to execute it, the lambda specific runtime class is irrelevant. If you have the target method, you can [create the lambda instance without third party libraries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html).

Of course, you can use ASM to analyze the target method’s code to transfer it (and all dependencies) to the remote side, but note that this is no different from transferring arbitrary `Function` implementations; the fact that there is a layer of a runtime generated class created via lambda expression does not help you in any way.