# How to inspect java method references (double colon) operator usages in classes during build time

Tags: java, bytecode, static-analysis, method-reference

Is there a way to detect usages of java method reference (double colon) operator inside the code?

I need to discover all instance/static method references used in a given class in order to be able to detect some errors (must verify that the target method has a particular annotation - @Good in the below example) during build time. As by convention a method reference should be used only to some of the methods when it is passed to a constructor of some helper class (Info in the below example).

```
class X {

    Info init() {
        return new Info(X::beta);  // good code: target method has @Good annotation
        return new Info(X::alpha); // bad code:  target method has no @Good annotation
    }
    
    void alpha() {
    }
    
    @Good
    void beta() {
    }
}
```

The intention is to be able to click on the method reference as this makes it easy to follow as otherwise if just passing Method instance or just method name it would lack this ability.

(The example is not very good but I'm now allowed to share more details, sorry about that!)

I can see IntelliJ IDEA "knows" about them - when you ctrl+click on them it navigates to the target method so there should be some form of a static analysis used there.

I'm already using ObjectWeb ASM to detect invocations to certain methods but it seems it lacks the ability to detect method references (::)

***EDIT***:
Just a note that you can also pass `new Info(x -> x.alpha())` as [@Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas) below mentioned in the comments but this would not pass our review process but I guess the additional ability to detect it would not hurt.

***EDIT2***: *What exactly are you trying to achieve with these checks? What makes beta worthy of receiving the annotation?*

**Answer**:
When the init() method is called we obtain the Info instance and from it obtain the lambda which must be a method reference. Then we use javassist ProxyFactory and create a sub-class of class X then instantiate it and intercept all its methods via setting a method handler. So now it is safe to execute the lambda without allowing it to make any side effects - the method body is skipped and the only thing we do is to capture which is the X method that the lambda actually is calling - in the example this will lead to a java.lang.Method instance pointing to X.beta or X.alpha method. Then we can check if it has the @Good annotation and proceed accordingly - which is to call the lambda without any proxying, but that call might happen later, like a millisecond later or an hour later. If there is no @Good annotation we cannot proceed - it is a bug.

So the problem is that this will happen at runtime later and there might be a bug not caught early enough and that is the reason I would like to inspect the X class at build time and catch all the bugs :)

Comment: Since the `Info` constructor seems to have a functional interface parameter (or otherwise the method reference wouldn't work) it could also be called as `new Info(x -> x.alpha())` so you'd need to check any lambdas. You've mentioned ASM already so maybe you want to look into how ASM handles lambdas (method references should be very similar to that). Maybe this helps already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133243/how-lambda-expressions-are-translate-in-java-byte-code

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with these checks? What makes `beta` worthy of receiving the annotation?

Comment: @knittl, I have answered in EDIT2 above, thanks for asking!

Comment: I can’t follow your explanation. You say that you are selecting at runtime between two different behaviors, depending on whether the annotation is present or not. So why is the absence of the annotation suddenly an error that you want to catch at build-time?

Comment: @Holger, I have upated it - "If there is no [at]Good annotation we cannot proceed - it is a bug." ... Keep in mind that I'm trying to come up with a reasonable example without revealing details that I'm not allowed to ... I now the above example is not good enogh, but the point is that it would be useful to be able to detect a method reference operators and to be able to differentiate them from lambdas..

Comment: It’s still confusing. When it has the annotation, you’ll “call the lambda without any proxying” and when it hasn’t, you “cannot proceed”. So what is this proxying for that you described right before those statements?

Comment: @bodrin: What I do not get is: why can you proxy method refs, but cannot proxy lambdas? In the end, both call a method

Comment: Maybe, I found the reason for the confusion. That section is preceded by “*What exactly are you trying to achieve with these checks? What makes beta worthy of receiving the annotation?  Answer:*”, so readers like me thought that an answer to why you need to check for the annotation was following but apparently, that’s a actually only a description of a way to check for the presence of the annotation, at runtime. So you didn’t explain why you need to check for the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, as I'm neither very proficient with ASM nor sure if this approach addresses your problem. Having said that, I found that, in a similar setting, `asm.MethodVisitor` calls `MethodVisitor.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(...)` for (some? all?) method references.

E.g., if I compile this variant of your class `X` along with an `Info`:

```
class Info {
    public Info(Runnable alpha) {}
}

class X {

    Info init() { return new Info(this::alpha); }
    void alpha() {}
}
```

... and I then feed the resulting `X.class` into a mini `ClassVisitor` + printing `MethodVisitor` (Groovy for brevity):

```
class MyMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {

    MyMethodVisitor(MethodVisitor parent) { super(Opcodes.ASM8, parent) }

    @Override
    void visitInvokeDynamicInsn(String name, String descriptor, Handle bootstrapMethodHandle, Object... bootstrapMethodArguments) {
        println "visitInvokeDynamicInsn($name, $descriptor, $bootstrapMethodHandle, $bootstrapMethodArguments)"
        super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(name, descriptor, bootstrapMethodHandle, bootstrapMethodArguments)
    }
}

class MyClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
    MyClassVisitor() { super(Opcodes.ASM8) }

    @Override
    MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        println "Starting method '$name'"
        new MyMethodVisitor(super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions))
    }
}

def clr = new ClassReader(new File("./X.class").bytes)
clr.accept(new MyClassVisitor(), ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES)
```

Then the method visitor prints, amongst other details, a call to `visitInvokeDynamicInsn` from within the method visitation of `X::init` with the desired `X::alpha` among the arguments (the `xyz` being my local package):

```
Visiting method '<init>'
Visiting method 'init'
visitInvokeDynamicInsn(run, (xyz/X;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;,
    java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; (6),
    [()V, xyz/X.alpha()V (5), ()V])
Visiting method 'alpha'
```

So it would seem possible to peel the method out of those arguments. I am not sure if this reliable (e.g., whether this bytecode is guaranteed by specification, or whether it can depend on compilation/optimization details).

Comment: I'm also wondering if it is reliable, but note that org.objectweb.asm is actually present as jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm in OpenJDK and it is used to generate the lambda call sites. I have upvoted as this at least tells me all the lambdas/method refs invocations per class method. Thanks for the help! Unfortunately it does not tell me whether the lambda is passed to Info constructor and I actually need all the lambdas that are used in all the Info constructors (in order to verify only them).